# Error: Error in reorganization. Reorganization Failed

Tags: genexus

I had a working web app in Genexus. I added identity to the id column of an existing transaction, added a new column and tried to play the web app. It keeps saying reorganization failed. Where is the log in which I can see what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may access the output log by the menu view, other tool windows, output. After it has opened, make sure that the combo inside it is selected to "build".

Comment: Certainly, is in this window that i get this message. Reorganization Failed
error: Error in reorganization Run Developer Menu Failed. But, is there a way to know why reorganization is failing? i mean, a log that describes the root cause of the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can always log any communication between the app and the DBMS enabling log level property (inside generator's properties) to any value different than 0. I perfer to use "all" when i need.